# Calculating eigenvalues for a $3 \times 3$ matrix without solving a cubic

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, factoring, cubics

> [image]

---

I am trying to find the eigenvalue for question **(h)**, however I am unable to factor out and find the eigenvalues(roots) after I take the determinant of the characteristic equation.

Let  $x$ be an eigenvalue. I am left with $$(-2-x)((1-x)(6-x)-4)-2(2(6-x)-2)+(4-(1-x))=0.$$

As for hint: says do not expand to try and solve the resulting cubic, I am looking for help on how to factorize this question so I do not need to solve a cubic polynomial

Anyway the correct answer for the eigenvalues are $x_1=1$, $x_2=-3$ and $x_3=7$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that what you say are the eigenvalues don't satisfy what you say is the characteristic equation, so one of the two must be wrong.

Comment: In you equation it is not $-(2-x)$ but $-(2+x)$

Answer (score 1):

$$A= \left[
\begin{array}{}
  -2&2&1\\
  2&1&2\\
  1&2&6
\end{array}
\right] \iff det(A-\lambda I) = \left|
\begin{array}{}
  -2-\lambda&2&1\\
  2&1-\lambda&2\\
  1&2&6-\lambda
\end{array}
\right|$$

$\\$

$$\left|
\begin{array}{}
  -2-\lambda&2&1\\
  2&1-\lambda&2\\
  1&2&6-\lambda
\end{array}
\right| \iff \left|
\begin{array}{}
  -2-\lambda&2&1\\
  0&-3-\lambda&-10+2\lambda\\
  1&2&6-\lambda
\end{array}
\right|$$

$\\$

$$ \iff \left|
\begin{array}{}
  0&6+2\lambda&1+(6-\lambda)(2+\lambda)\\
  0&-3-\lambda&-10+2\lambda\\
  1&2&6-\lambda
\end{array}
\right| \iff \left|
\begin{array}{}
  6+2\lambda&1+(6-\lambda)(2+\lambda)\\
  -3-\lambda&-10+2\lambda
\end{array}
\right|$$

$\\$

$$ \iff 4(3+\lambda)(-5+\lambda)+(3+\lambda)+(3+\lambda)(6-\lambda)(2+\lambda)$$

$\\$

$$ \iff (3+\lambda)[4(-5+\lambda)+1+(6-\lambda)(2+\lambda)]$$

$\\$

$$ \iff (3+\lambda)[-20+4\lambda+1+12+6\lambda-2\lambda-\lambda^2]$$

$\\$

$$ \iff (3+\lambda)[-7+8\lambda-\lambda^2]$$

$\\$

$$ \iff -(3+\lambda)(\lambda-7)(\lambda-1)$$

Now it is easy to solve:
$$-(3+\lambda)(\lambda-7)(\lambda-1)=0,$$

i.e we have $\lambda_1=-3, \lambda_2=7, \lambda_3=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the equation is
$$
\left( { - 2 - x} \right)\left[ {\left( {1 - x} \right)\left( {6 - x} \right) - 4} \right] - 2\left[ {2\left( {6 - x} \right) - 2} \right] + 4 - \left( {1 - x} \right) = 0
$$
you get
$$
\left( { - 2 - x} \right)\left( {1 - x} \right)\left( {6 - x} \right) - 4\left( { - 2 - x} \right) - 4\left( {6 - x} \right) + 8 - \left( {1 - x} \right) = 0
$$
thus
$$
\left( { - 2 - x} \right)\left( {1 - x} \right)\left( {6 - x} \right) - 4\left[ {\left( { - 2 - x} \right) + \left( {6 - x} \right) - 2} \right] - (1 - x) = 0
$$
and so
$$
\left( { - 2 - x} \right)\left( {1 - x} \right)\left( {6 - x} \right) - 9\left( {1 - x} \right) = 0
$$
and finally 
$$
\left( {1 - x} \right)\left[ {\left( { - 2 - x} \right)\left( {6 - x} \right) - 9} \right] = 0
$$
Now it is easy since you have $x^2-4x-21=0$ which has the solutions $x=7$ and $x=-3$.